# Laravel Query to get users from same country and city

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get users from *users* table. I have another table *user_details* which stores custom profile fields. The *user_details* table has four columns *id,user,user_register_field,value*.

```
id    user   user_register_field  value

1     1      gender               Male
2     1      city                 somecity
3     1      country              somecountry
4     2      gender               Female
5     2      city                 Null
6     2      country              somecountry
7     3      gender               Male
```

**Users.php**

```
public function Udetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserDetails','user');
}
```

Suppose user with user id 1 logged in & I want to show him the another users from same Country & City from which the user 1 is from.

Answer (score 1):

just do something like this:

```
User::whereHas('Udetails',function($q){
    $q->where('user_register_field','country')
        ->where('value',your_logged_users_country);
})->whereHas('Udetails',function($q){
    $q->where('user_register_field','city')
        ->where('value',your_logged_users_city);
})->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I have coded like this before. But problem is, some users don't have Countries selected in their profiles and does not have any relevant row in *user_details* table and some the same problem is with Cities also.  Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need some sort of [`Parameter Grouping`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping) criteria

```
User::whereHas('Udetails',function($query) use ($country, $city){
    $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_register_field', '=', 'country')
                  ->where('value', '=', $country);
        })->orWwhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_register_field', '=', 'city')
                  ->where('value', '=', $city);
        });
})->get();
```